# Disable List Throttling using webservice

Tags: web-services, resource-throttling

I am using `list.asmx` web service for getting List Items, currently List have around 5000+ data and while I am trying to call `spList.GetListItems()` method it gives error, because it exceeds threshold limit.

> "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list
>   view threshold enforced by the administrator."

I have also try something

```
ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = "<QueryThrottleMode>1</QueryThrottleMode>"
```

but not worked.

I can't use `SPQuery` or `SPList` & don't want to change it from Central Admin, So  How can I disable throttling using web service for list.

Comment: Try batching your calls, using Paging, using ListItemCollectionPositionNext: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to to do that via Web Service. The only place you configure it is using Central Administration Web Site.

You can resolve this issue by creating appropriated indexes in you Custom List.

Create index for all fields you are using inside the `Where` clause.

Comment: Thanks Amal, I can't change the default configuration, but i have tried to create indexes, but it gives same error. what i did was as list have already 5000+ records, so first increase default threshold value and then create indexer and then reset threshold value to default. After that i have tried to call GetListItems() method, but it gives error. PS : in where clause i am uses lookup field.

Comment: Lookup columns has known issues. This is a bug and unfortunately no workaround as per my knowledge.